# C Preprocessor Stringify enter\newline characters

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

So like many that have dealt with OpenGL Shaders in the past being able to write them without an extra program to convert them into a string has always been a want. So what I am looking for is a way to replace enter presses\newline characters in the source code with "\n" for example:

```
const char *sShaderSrc =
ConvertTextToString(
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 mModel;
uniform mat3 mNormal;
uniform mat4 mViewProj;

varying vec3 vNormal;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = (mViewProj *mModel) * vec4(aPos,1.0) ;
   vNormal =  mNormal*aNormal;
}
)
;
```

and then the preprocessor would convert it into

```
const char *sShaderSrc =
"#version 330 core\n\nlayout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\nlayout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;\n\nuniform mat4 mModel;\nuniform mat3 mNormal;\nuniform mat4 mViewProj;\n\nvarying vec3 vNormal;\n\nvoid main()\n{\n   gl_Position = (mViewProj *mModel) * vec4(aPos,1.0);\n   vNormal =  mNormal*aNormal;\n}\n"
;
```

that way if OpenGL gives errors when compiling then I get shader line numbers in the error message.

Help would be much appreciated. The only edge case I could think of is also dealing with the case if the text editior inserts "\r\n" or "\n".

I have tried

```
#define RAWSTRINGIFY(x) R#x

//then you do
RAWSTRINGIFY((
 //glsl code here...
))
```

but doesn't work the straight insertion

Comment: Please elaborate "but doesn't work the straight insertion" I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A Macro Solution (and why it doesn't work for your purpose)**

This can be implemented as a variadic macro so that it actually compiles.

```cpp
#define ConvertTextToString(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

Unfortunately, there are two problems preventing this from being useful in the scenario.

1. It still doesn't preserve the newlines, as the newlines are not passed to the macro. Macro expansion is done after tokenization, which means that by the time a macro is expanded, all the newlines are already gone. See [C++ preprocessor stringification that preserves newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19741257/12122460)
2. The `#version 330 core` is seen by the compiler as a preprocessor directive, which causes errors like this. There's no solution around this.

```
main.cpp:6:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive
#version 330 core
```

---

**Using Raw String Literals**

A solution to your intended use case (i.e. multiline string literals) is to use [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5460235/12122460) in C++. For example,

```cpp
const char* shaderSrc = R""""(
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
// ...
)"""";
```

Comment: yet another reason C/C++ frustrates lol. Their preprocessor system lacks a lot of useful preprocessing features. Anyways, thank you for your response

Comment: @yosmo78 Note that if you need more functionality than the standard preprocessor provides there's nothing to stop you 'pre-preprocessing' your source files with something like [`m4`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html).

Comment: @G.M. I know, just stinks it can't be done solely with features from the compiler. Meaning that the build system will increase with complexity